# Using Exoplayer Demo with Firebase Realtime Database

Tags: java, android, exoplayer

I am working on exoplayer. I don’t have any trouble about playing media by using "[media.exolist.json](https://github.com/google/ExoPlayer/tree/release-v2/demos/main/src/main/assets)" but i want to take the url from firebase realtime database. My realtime database looks like this:

[image: My realtime database]

How can i take uri from realtime database? Are there any other ways that you can suggest? Related codes are here:[SampleChooserActivity.java](https://github.com/google/ExoPlayer/blob/release-v2/demos/main/src/main/java/com/google/android/exoplayer2/demo/SampleChooserActivity.java)

Answer (score 0):

1) You will have to integrate firebase SDK and on start of the activity fetch the data from the database.
2) after getting the URL, prepare the player dynamically and pass the URL your video should play.